# Function not called in C

Tags: c, function

My functions `prefixSum` and `suffixSum` are not getting called in `main` function? I tried to google but couldn't find anything. What's the fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int A[1000];
int N;
int prefixSum(int i){
    int sum,j;
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        sum=sum+A[j];
    }
    return sum;
    }

int suffixSum(int i){
    int sum,j;
    for(j=i;j<N;j++){
        sum=sum+A[j];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(void) {
    int T,p,s,index,temp,t,k;
    int total=99999;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(t=0;t<T;t++){
        scanf("%d",&N);
        for(k=0;k<N;k++){
            p=prefixSum(k);
            s=suffixSum(k);
            temp=p+s;
            if(temp<total){
                index=k;
            }
        }
        printf("%d",index);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What was the input you tried? and what was the output of the program?

Comment: not called? what happens? hint: input 0 and 0 and no loops are executed

Comment: How do you know they're not getting called? I don't believe you! But you're using `sum` uninitialized in both of them, yielding unspecified results.

Comment: N is global check 3rd line

Comment: Btw, write **readable** code please. It helps **you** (and us as well) to spot errors. This means: 1.) declare **one** variable per line 2.) declare these variables close to where they are used 3.) format your code with **spaces** (before opening parantheses that are not function calls, after semicolons and commas, around some operators like assignment and `+`, and so on ...)

Comment: plus your code depends on user input. Provide a [mcve] that doesn't involve guessing.

Comment: No sign of any code populating the array `A` either

Comment: It will be called but it may not work as intended. Other than uninitialized `sum` and array `A` it looks okay. What are your inputs?

Comment: Debugger............

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. shows how to check for errors on calls to `scanf()`
2. contains comments on the problems in the code
3. highlights several areas where undefined behavior can/will occur
4. shows one way to limit the scope of variables
5. properly initializes local variable
6. documents why each header file is being included
7. shows appropriate usage of horizontal spacing
8. incorporates the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
9. shows what is meant by: separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via one blank line
10. shows what is meant by: separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent).

The code does not prompt the user, so the user will be looking at a blank screen with a blinking cursor and no idea as to what to do next.
In the proposed code, I have not corrected that problem; however, you should.

For further ease of readability and understanding, variable names and parameter names should indicate 'content' or 'usage' (or better, both).

And now the code, with several corrections:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE 

// NOTE: the array A[] and N are in file global space, so are initialized to all 0's 
int A[ 1000 ];
int N;


int prefixSum( int i )
{
    //int sum;    // this is on the stack, so not initialized to any specific value
    int sum = 0;

    //int j;
    for( int j=0; j<=i; j++ )  // limit scope of variables to where they are used
    {
        // this line has no effect because all values in A[] are 0
        // accessing the content of an uninitialized variable 'sum' is undefined behavior
        sum = sum + A[j]; // can also be written as: 'sum += A[j];'
    }

    return sum;
} // end function: prefixSum


int suffixSum( int i )
{
    //int sum;    // this is on the stack, so not initialized to any specific value
    int sum = 0;

    //int j;
    for( int j=i; j<N; j++ )  // limit scope of variables to where they are used
    {
        // this line has no effect because all values in A[] are 0
        // accessing the content of an uninitialized variable 'sum' is undefined behavior
        sum = sum + A[j]; // can also be written as: 'sum += A[j];'
    }
    return sum;
} // end function: suffixSum


int main( void )
{
    // follow the axiom:
    // only one statement per line
    // and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.
    int T;
    int p;
    int s;
    int index;
    int temp;

    //int t;  -- keep variable declarations tightly knit to where they are used
    //int k;

    int total=99999;

    // always check the returned value
    // from any of the 'scanf()' family of functions
    // to assure the operation was successful
    // scanf("%d",&T);
    if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &T ) )
    {
        perror( "scanf failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    for(int t=0; t<T; t++ )
    {
        // what happpens when the user enters a number greater than 999?
        // then would be accessing beyond end of array 'A[]',
        // which is undefined behavior
        scanf( "%d", &N );  // -- also needs error checking

        for( int k=0; k<N; k++ )
        {
            p = prefixSum( k );
            s = suffixSum( k );
            temp = p+s;

            if( temp < total )
            {
                index = k;
            }
        }

        // the output stream 'stdout' is buffered.
        // to have immediate display on the terminal
        // the last item in the format string needs to be a 'newline' sequence
        //printf("%d",index);
        printf( "%d\n", index );
    }
    return 0;
} // end function: main
```